# iOS: Deeplinking in the background

Tags: ios, deep-linking

Is it possible in iOS to deep-link from one app to another when asleep?

Say I want to open AppTwo from AppOne, and in AppOne I have:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

If AppOne is running in the background and AppTwo is not running, will this message ever get received? When debugging, I can see that the above line of code is executed, but AppTwo's applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions doesn't ever appear to get called. I suspect that it's not possible, but I've yet to find any official Apple documentation regarding this.

Comment: did you register a scheme in the targeted app

Comment: You can't launch app 2 when app 1 is in the background as that would interrupt the user

Comment: Yes, you can't do that.